# Global scope within document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a globally accessible variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601773/how-do-i-create-a-globally-accessible-variable)

How to make variables and functions within:

```
$(function() {  })
```

global scope?

Comment: What prevents you from declaring them globally?

Comment: @Felix  yes  ( window.variable = variable)  is working - duplicate question.. my bad..  thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have these choices.

1. You can predeclare the variables before the function scope.
2. You can use the `window` prefix to make them in the global scope.

### Option #1:

```
var myGlobal;
$(function() { 
    myGlobal = 4;
});
```

### Option #2:

```
$(function() { 
    window.myGlobal = 4;
});
```

Comment: hmm, the only purpose of $(function() {  })  is to fire on document ready right?  so I could declare functions before $(function() {  }) and set them in the $(function() {  }) ?

Comment: Also, in Option #1,  if you change myGlobal in $(function() {  }), does it change globally because it was declared globally?

Comment: @bushdiver - yes.  The javascript interpreter looks first in the local scope.  If the variable isn't found in the local scope, then it looks at higher scopes up to the global scope for a variable with that name.

Comment: @jfriend00 wouldn't it be better to use JS namespace conventions to minimize risk of variable name collisions in the global scope?

Comment: @rafiki_rafi - the question was specifically about how to put things in the global scope.  A much longer discussion could discuss why putting unnecessary things in the global scope is a bad thing, but that is not what was asked and we'd need to know a lot more about the OP's actual problem to know what else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the code inside the closure be available globally, then I would recommend using [JS namespaces](http://elegantcode.com/2011/01/26/basic-javascript-part-8-namespaces/). For example:

```
var myNameSpace = myNameSpace || {} //create a namespace
```

Using namespacing ensures you're not polluting the global namespace. Then inside your closure, you can extend the namespace with objects, functions, and variables:

```
$(function(){
  if(myNameSpace){
    myNameSpace.function1 = function(p1){ return $(p1).val() };
    myNameSpace.function2 = function(p2){ return $(p2).val() };
  }
})();
```

function1 and function2 should be available "globally" via myNameSpace.

Comment: As one can see from the [jQuery.ready doc page](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), the OP's code is a shorthand notation for `.ready()`.  Your answer is not what the OP was asking.

Comment: Ah, good to know, I'm used to seeing $(document).ready(handler), not the way OP wrote it! Post has been edited not to mislead others